# MATLAB: How to import a batch of image iteratively in a folder and export processed image iteratively?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Here is what I need to do:

All images (40,000 of them) are under a file and they are all named "roof_*.jpg";

```
for i=1:40000  

  Step One: import and image from the file directory 

   "/Users/gaochenying1/Documents/MATLAB/roof_images_copy"

   Step Two: process it (that part I can do);

   Step Three: export processed image into the same file but named

   "r_roof_*.jpg";

end
```

I've tried

```
filelist = dir([fileparts('/Users/gaochenying1/Documents/MATLAB/roof_images_copy') filesep 'roof_*.jpg']);

fileNames = {filelist.name}';
```

It didn't work at all!

Comment: This is a software issue and as such is off-topic on Cross Validated - see our [help/on-topic]. I think this should be on-topic on Stack Overflow - if you wait, and enough people agree with me, we can migrate this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
folder = 'C:/Users/gaochenying1/Documents/MATLAB/roof_images_copy';
files = dir(fullfile(folder,'roof_*.jpg'));
for i = 1:length(files)
  fn_i = files(i).name;
  im_in = imread(fullfile(folder,fn_i));
  im_out = processingfunction(im_in);
  imwrite(im_out,fullfile(folder,sprintf('r_%s',fn_i)));
end
```